# Get the coordinates QGraphicsLineItem?

Tags: c++, qt

I can not get the coordinates of an object in another class.

I changed some lines.

cisimEkle.cpp

```
void cisimEkle::cizgileriCiz(int x1, int x2, int y1, int y2)
{
    QPen kalem(Qt::black);
    kalem.setStyle(Qt::SolidLine);
    kalem.setWidth(1);

    QLine cizgi1Koordinati(x1,0,x1,y1);
    QLine cizgi2Koordinati(x2,0,x2,y2);
    QLine cizgi3Koordinati(x1,y1,x2,y2);

    cizgi1 = gsCisim->addLine(cizgi1Koordinati,kalem);
    cizgi2 = gsCisim->addLine(cizgi2Koordinati,kalem);
    cizgi3 = gsCisim->addLine(cizgi3Koordinati,kalem);

    qDebug() << cizgi2->line().p1();//QPointF(100,0) 
....
}
```

old mainwindow.cpp

```
void MainWindow::on_btnEkle_clicked()
{
    int index = ui->cmbCisimler->currentIndex();
    QList<QGraphicsItem*> list = cisimListesi.at(index)->childItems();
    QGraphicsLineItem gl;

    foreach (QGraphicsItem* item, list) {
        gsKiris->addItem(item);
        switch (item->type()) {
        case 6:
            gl.setParentItem(item->parentItem()); //item is from cisimEkle.cpp 
            qDebug() << "Çizgi(6)";
            qDebug() << "p1:"<<  gl.line().p1();////QPointF(0,0)
            break;
...
}
```

but when I look at the debug mode:

[image]

How can I solve this problem?

**Answer:**
new mainwindow.cpp

```
void MainWindow::on_btnEkle_clicked()
{
    int index = ui->cmbCisimler->currentIndex();
    QList<QGraphicsItem*> list = cisimListesi.at(index)->childItems();

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i) {
        gsKiris->addItem(list.at(i));
        if (list.at(i)->type() == 6) {
            QGraphicsLineItem* gl = dynamic_cast<QGraphicsLineItem*>(list.at(i)); // QGraphicsLineItem to QGraphicsItem
            qDebug() << "p1:"<<  gl->line().p1();
        }
    }
....
}
```

Comment: Don't add "[SOLVED]" to the title. Post your solution *as an answer*. (Yes, you can post and accept an answer to your own question.)